# Prove that HM of two natural number is not a natural number

Tags: proof-verification, proof-writing, natural-numbers

I've been trying to prove this

> Given any $x,y \in \mathbb{N}$ with $x < y$, $\dfrac{2xy}{x+y} \not\in \mathbb{N}$.

Here's what I tried:

For contradiction, suppose there were some $x,y \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\dfrac{2xy}{x+y}\in \mathbb{N}$. Let $\dfrac{2xy}{x+y}=H$. Then $y\left( 2\dfrac{x}{H}-1 \right)= x$. Since $H$ is the harmonic mean of $x$ and $y$, we have $0<x<H<y$. Now, $0< \dfrac{x}{H} < 1$, thus, $\dfrac{x}{H} \not\in \mathbb{N}$. Hence, we have $x= y\left( 2\dfrac{x}{H}-1 \right) \not \in \mathbb{N}$. This leads to contradicts the fact that $x$ was in $\mathbb{N}$. This ends the proof.

Is my proof correct? What would be other way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proof can't be right, since what you're trying to prove is not true.

In particular $(x,y)=(3,6)$ is a **counterexample**: $\frac{2\cdot 3\cdot 6}{3+6}=\frac{36}{9}=4\in\mathbb N$.

For this counteexample it is true that $\frac xH = \frac 34$ is not a natural number. And $2\frac xH-1 = \frac12$ is not a natural number either. But when we multiply that with $6$, the denominator disappears.